# django - class based views to post from user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a user post blog. I want the author name to be generated from the login but instead it is displaying the admin user name
this is my Models.py
[image]

I have used class based views to create post
this is my views.py
[image]

I am accessing author name in html as request.user.username
articledetail.html
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there are two error in your code :

- the first  : "the default=1 in author field in your model"

it's not really an error but that's not have a sense here, we use it to put a default value if any value was entered

- the second error is you must tell Django what we have to put in the author field. To do that You only need to grab the user from the request and feed that into the created instance before it is saved. This could be done in form_valid(), so just uncomment the function form_valid() that u already done.

Comment: I am getting an error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'User'.  Do I need to change my settings.

Comment: no the thing that's cause that is the capital letter 'U' in user : change User to user : self.request.user

Answer (score 0):

To access current username in html/jinja2 template you have to use `{{ user.username }}` instead of `{{ request.user.username }}`.

But in your case to access the author username that published the post you have to write use
the `{{ post.author.username }}`

```
{{ post.author.first_name }} #gets author's firstname
```